# GitHub not setting global user name and Password

Tags: git

I am trying to use git and when I try to use the following I got error:
C:\Users\Tarishah\Documents\JulyDevOpsProjects\MyFirstGitProject>git commit -m "todayfirst project"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'Tarishah@FourStars.(none)')
somehow it is getting wrong email address and when I try to make correction I got following permission denied error:

C:\Users\Tarishah\Documents\JulyDevOpsProjects\MyFirstGitProject>git config --global user.email "tarishah1992@gmail.com"
error: could not lock config file C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.gitconfig: Permission denied

And if I do the following got again error message:
C:\Users\Tarishah\Documents\JulyDevOpsProjects\MyFirstGitProject>git config --global -l
fatal: unable to read config file 'C:/WINDOWS/system32/config/systemprofile/.gitconfig': No such file or directory.

I have set my Environment Variables as following:
System Variables:

HOME  %USERPROFILE%

Please let me know how to fix this issue,  and do a "git commit" without any error. I have tried my all resources.

Answer (score 0):

Just try again omitting `--global` from commands. Hopefully this will fix the issue.

```
    $ git config user.email "Your@emailaddres.com"
    $ git config user.name "Your name"
```

With `--global` option, it is trying to modify in `C:/WINDOWS/system32/` that requires administrator privileges.

Comment: @Tarishah You can upvote to accept this as an answer. Refer here - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.